# Filter XML with contains syntax

Tags: .net, xml, sharepoint, workflow-foundation

I have a XML output and I need to find the TemplateID where Name contains "Request Modification"

this gives me all 3 Names.     /defaultNS:WorkflowTemplates/defaultNS:WorkflowTemplate/@Name

this doesn't do nothing either
/defaultNS:WorkflowTemplates/defaultNS:WorkflowTemplate[contains(./Name/text(),'Request Modification')]/defaultNS:WorkflowTemplateIdSet/@TemplateId

```
<WorkflowTemplates xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/workflow/">
    <WorkflowTemplate Name="set item permission" Description="" InstantiationUrl="https://team.nov.com/lao/Operation/Colorado/_layouts/NintexWorkflow/StartWorkflow.aspx?List=91639734-9479-4233-ab62-9a954ce31834&amp;ID=14&amp;TemplateID={a27abacf-0596-4638-9251-12b29ced721b}&amp;Web={e58c31db-d234-470e-994b-93d1e5fdb11a}">
        <WorkflowTemplateIdSet TemplateId="a27abacf-0596-4638-9251-12b29ced721b" BaseId="f851d0cb-82a9-472e-bfd9-eaffe26517e1" />
        <AssociationData>
            <string>&lt;Data&gt;&lt;people_Station_Members /&gt;&lt;var_WS_Error /&gt;&lt;workflowLink /&gt;&lt;var_Station_Member /&gt;&lt;var_WorkflowExistsResult /&gt;&lt;/Data&gt;</string>
        </AssociationData>
        <Metadata>
            <InitiationCategories>
                <string>General;#List</string>
            </InitiationCategories>
        </Metadata>
    </WorkflowTemplate>
    <WorkflowTemplate Name="Request Modification" Description="" InstantiationUrl="https://team.nov.com/lao/Operation/Colorado/_layouts/NintexWorkflow/StartWorkflow.aspx?List=91639734-9479-4233-ab62-9a954ce31834&amp;ID=14&amp;TemplateID={c14e3ac5-1edd-48ab-a361-2b97bf7a4382}&amp;Web={e58c31db-d234-470e-994b-93d1e5fdb11a}">
        <WorkflowTemplateIdSet TemplateId="c14e3ac5-1edd-48ab-a361-2b97bf7a4382" BaseId="1f35c9d9-17a8-44a7-8fcd-016250515554" />
        <AssociationData>
            <string>&lt;Data&gt;&lt;var_DupFileInDraftFolder /&gt;&lt;int_DupCount&gt;0&lt;/int_DupCount&gt;&lt;coll_DupFilesInDraftFolder /&gt;&lt;var_CopyResult /&gt;&lt;/Data&gt;</string>
        </AssociationData>
        <Metadata>
            <InitiationCategories>
                <string>General;#List</string>
            </InitiationCategories>
        </Metadata>
    </WorkflowTemplate>
    <WorkflowTemplate Name="Submit For Approval and Publish" Description="" InstantiationUrl="https://team.nov.com/lao/Operation/Colorado/_layouts/NintexWorkflow/StartWorkflow.aspx?List=91639734-9479-4233-ab62-9a954ce31834&amp;ID=14&amp;TemplateID={9596bd67-8493-4ade-9613-d7c3da507816}&amp;Web={e58c31db-d234-470e-994b-93d1e5fdb11a}">
        <WorkflowTemplateIdSet TemplateId="9596bd67-8493-4ade-9613-d7c3da507816" BaseId="98c707af-b7a4-4e32-8df3-93ed1f9ea7d9" />
        <AssociationData>
            <string>&lt;Data&gt;&lt;Approvers_x005F_x0020_Level_x005F_x0020_1 /&gt;&lt;Approvers_x005F_x0020_Level_x005F_x0020_2 /&gt;&lt;/Data&gt;</string>
        </AssociationData>
        <Metadata>
            <InitiationCategories>
                <string>General;#List</string>
            </InitiationCategories>
        </Metadata>
    </WorkflowTemplate>
</WorkflowTemplates>
```

Answer (score 0):

These worked.

//defaultNS:WorkflowTemplate[@Name='Request Modification']/@InstantiationUrl
Result:
https://team.nov.com/lao/Operation/Colorado/_layouts/NintexWorkflow/StartWorkflow.aspx?List=91639734-9479-4233-ab62-9a954ce31834&ID=14&TemplateID={c14e3ac5-1edd-48ab-a361-2b97bf7a4382}&Web={e58c31db-d234-470e-994b-93d1e5fdb11a}

//defaultNS:WorkflowTemplate[@Name='Request Modification']/defaultNS:WorkflowTemplateIdSet/@TemplateId
Result: Output 1
    TemplateId="c14e3ac5-1edd-48ab-a361-2b97bf7a4382"